# Finding a value in array x that maximizes its corresponding value in array y

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, minimize, maximize

I have two arrays.

The first array is called ret_arr and it contains the returns of different portfolios.
The second array is called vol_arr and it contains the volatility of those same portfolios.

If I wanted to find an element in the vol_array that is 0.2±0.01, which maximizes its corresponding element in the ret_arr, how would I do so?

The reason I am providing a tolerance of 0.01 is because the numbers in the vol_arr will not be exactly 0.2 and I want to sample a lot of points around that volatility level.

I know that I can do something like `vol_arr.sort()` and `ret_arr.sort()` and then just eyeball them to identify which has the best return at each volatility level, but it there a way to automate this?

My first attempt was to run this:

```
import numpy as np
def find_nearest(array, value):
    array = np.asarray(array)
    idx = (np.abs(array - value)).argmin()
    return array[idx]

array = ret_arr
print(array)

value = 0.08

print(find_nearest(array, value))
```

But this just finds the element in the `ret_arr` closest to the value I provided.

I would rather provide the vol level, give it some tolerance, and have the code loop over all values within that tolerance, and tell me the index that has the volatility level within the tolerance defined with the best return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
vol = 0.2
# Find indices of vol +/- 0.01 in the vol_arr
indices = np.where((vol_arr>vol-0.01) & (vol_arr<vol+0.01))
# Find the maximum return in the corresponding ret_arr
max_return = ret_arr[indices].max()
# Corresponding index from maximum return
max_index = ret_arr[indices].argmax()
# Look up the corresponding volatility
vol_index = indices[0][max_index]
vol_value = vol_arr[vol_index]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand your question correctly, if you want to find the element in iterable `a` which maximizes the corresponding value in `b`:

```
import numpy as np
max_index = np.argmax(b)
a[max_index]
```

This of course requires `a` and `b` to have the same length.